# Python Flask WTForms - appending files based on user input

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm having some difficulties finding information about this:

I'm using FLASK and Python for this.
I would like the user to input some text in an HTML form, and upon submission, the text to be sent to python and create/append a file. (WPA_SUPPLICANT) to ultimately connect the user to the wireless network.

Please help me out with the flask code for this action.
this is the closest thing I could find! I can't figure out what the template for this code should look like.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   timeString = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
   f=open('/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf','r')
   fp=f.read()
   templateData = {
      'title' : 'HELLO!',
      'time': timeString,
      'WPA': fp
      }
   f.close()
   return render_template('main.html', **templateData)

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
   newWPA=request.form['indexMain']
   print newWPA
   f=open('/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf','w')
   f.write(newWPA)
   f.close
   return redirect(url_for('hello'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Please advise! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling simple forms is prominently featured in the Flask [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request) and [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object).  Use `request.form` to access form data.  Using WTForms is even simpler, and is clearly explained in the [docs] as well.

`project/app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

app = Flask(__name__)

class WifiForm(Form):
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired()])

@app.route('/wifi-password', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wifi_password():
    form = WifiForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        password = form.password.data

        with open('/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf', 'w') as f:
            f.write('valid conf file with password')

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('wifi_password.html', form=form)
```

`project/templates/wifi_password.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WiFi Password</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.password }}
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```